# Bing's Geolocation Maps API - postal codes in Mexico

Tags: geolocation, bing, bing-api, bing-maps

I am having issues finding any geolocation data on Mexico using bing's services.  Example:

http://dev.virtualearth.net/REST/v1/Locations?countryRegion=MX&postalCode=66250&maxResults=1&key={my key}

Just gives me a central point for Mexico...  In fact, I have tried 15-20 postal codes, not one has any specific location data for that postal code.

Am I doing something wrong?  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bing Maps does not support postal codes in Mexico.

Comment: Is there a way to know wichh coutries it supports postal codes?

Comment: Not really. Many countries don't have postal codes systems. Some d, but the data is usually not available with spatial data. While others are available, but the data may not be accurate enough to put into the maps.